# Unable to play video in IE 11

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-11, mp4

When I try to access a mp4 video url in IE 11 it prompts the user to download the video instead of playing it in the browser. But I am able to play the video in Chrome/Firefox. Here is a sample url, https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4

Is it because IE 11 does not have any in-built Media Player

How to make the video stream in IE 11 instead of prompting the user to download. Kindly help. I am using Windows 10 and IE 11.471.17134.0. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried HTML5 video tag?

Comment: Thanks for the input!! Just tried and it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because it is a file. It has extension .mp4

Any link with file in end will be downloading, except in modern browsers this option has changed to autoplay, since a player has been embeded in modern browsers. Thats why opening video or audio file with most popular extensions like .mp4 will be auto playable.

If on modern you want to download, then from menu toolbar choosing File->save (shortcut CTRL+S) on some for better faster response can right click and choose save video.

On IE it does just basic downloading.

Anyways would recommend to let IE stay on its own way and not use it for malware insecurities and vulnerabilities. Use from securest ones Chrome, Opera, Firefox or any other top browsers.